# jQuery plugin similar to a contact list ordered alphabetically

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Do people know of any decent jQuery plugins that will present to the user a list of names that are alphabatized, just like the contacts in an iPhone directory.

That is, if I click on "T", it will give me all the names beginning with "T" etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are two popular plugins that replicate the iPhone contact list.

1. http://devgrow.com/slidernav/
2. http://www.brianhadaway.com/iphone-apple-style-alphabetical-contact-lists-in-html-css-javascript-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery Table Sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) lets you sort table columns alphabetically, but I don't think you can select it by letter. May get you started though.

Comment: Thanks @Tristar Web Design but  do recall a plugin out there that does exactly what I need but just can't recall it.